# Using Custom Raw XML in Android

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm trying to use a custom raw xml file for loading unique styles onto GroundOverlays in a GoogleMap.  The XML would make this easy as I could control the style of these overlays from the resource folder. However, When I try to get the XML using the getXML function I get an error,

`val styles = context.resources.getXml(R.raw.map_styles)`
The error I get is 
`Expected resource is of type xml`

But it is an xml file with a .xml extension in the raw folder.
It is named, `map_styles.xml` under /raw.

Inside of the folder I have,

```
<MapStyles>
    <MapStyle
        id="day_style"
        timeStart="sunrise_after"
        timeEnd="sunset_before"
        styleSheet="R.raw.day_style"
        >

        <Border
            id="day_on_day"
            priority="0"
            specificRegion="False"
            timeStart="sunrise_after"
            timeEnd="sunset_before"
            >
            <StaticBorder>
                <Drawable></Drawable>
            </StaticBorder>
        </Border>
    <MapStyle>
<MapStyles>
```

Not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: Put it in `res/xml/`, not `res/raw/`.

Answer (score 0):

As per CommonsWare's advice, simply put the xml file into res/xml, not res/raw.

Thanks!